# Regex for password: repetitive characters

Tags: regex

I have following conditions for password validation.

- Password must be at least eight (8) characters in length.
- Password must contain both alpha and numeric characters.
- Password cannot have repeating characters (e.g. AA, aa, 00, 11, etc.).

I have tried with below regex, but missing repeating characters.
Any suggestions?

```
var passw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8}$/;
```

Comment: Why?! Are you deliberately trying to lower the entropy of your passwords? I can't use "aardvark2" as my password? Randomly generated passwords will now have to be vetted to make sure they don't contain repeated characters? You're not increasing security at all here.

Comment: yes..you are right..but this is specific requirement.

Comment: They're trying to keep people from using passwords like `aaaa1111`

Comment: @Barmar Without additional context information available to an attacker, `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is actually harder to guess than `monkey12`. :)

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. While it does for ensure you have a number, lowercase, and uppercase, it ensures that they appear *in that order*

Answer (score 2):

The regex to match repeated characters is `/(.)\1/`.
I would simply do this as a two-step verification, no need to roll it into one regex.
As pointed out in the comments, this only *lowers* password entropy and thereby security though.

Answer (score 2):

Look aheads are your friend:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.)\1).{8,}
```

Comment: this is taking more that 8 characters as well

Comment: @user1037452 Sentence #2 of the question: *Password must be **at least** eight (8) characters in length*

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(?>([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)){8,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ..got answer `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*(.)\1).{8}$`