# Regex -Capture repetitive characters from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I'm trying to find its repetitive characters and I don't want to include them in the result array.

**This is my string(can be also number):**

```
var str = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB";
```

**This is my goal:**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

**and what I have so far:**

```
var str = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB";
var regex = /(.)\1/g;
str.match(regex); 
//["AA", "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for password: repetative characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928791/regex-for-password-repetative-characters)

Comment: `var regex = /(.)\1*/g;
str.match(regex).map(x=>x.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try it like this with a negative lookahead `(?!` that asserts that what follows is not group 1 `\1`:

```js
var str = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB";
var regex = /(.)(?!\1)/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: Nice, simpler than mine for sure +1

Comment: Thanks, howcome I didn't remember lookaheads!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `exec` and loop over matches adding each capture to an array.

```js
var s = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB",
    r = /(.)\1*/g,
    a = []
while((m = r.exec(s)) !== null) {
  a.push(m[1])
}
console.log(a)
```